# What could be some ' Consequences of Not Verifying the Issuer ' of JWT token?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt, access-token, spring-security-oauth2

Let's say some applicaton named 'AppX' grants access to their API's through JWT tokens and uses it's own internal independent project to grant JWT tokens.

The JWT Issuer app does not include "iss" - the issuer field in JWT token. So the 'AppX' application is NOT verifying the "iss" - issuer of JWT token.

**I want to understand below points as deeply as possible:**
**1)** How can someone (outsider / insider) (ethical / unethical hacker) exploit this knowing / assuming that 'AppX' is not verifying the issuer?
**2)** Is it really necessary to verify the token issuer (iss field) as the Issuer app is internal? Given that anyone outside can make a request to get token.
**3)** What if JWT Token issuer is not internal, but we are sure about the URL to request the JWT token, does this require verification of issuer?
**4)** What are some best practices to verify the issuer?

You're welcome to suggest edit / improve the question / description.